# Program without main()

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C program without main function ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666540/c-program-without-main-function)

Can we write a c program without `main()` which can run and execute?

Please reply...

Comment: why are people curious about this at all? what possible value could an answer other than "no it's not possible" have? or is it meant to be a purely philosophical thought exercise? No offense intended, I am just really surprised this question has come up more than once.

Comment: It is possible, but it is extremely specific to the OS, some standard library stuff (if you care to use things like `FILE *stdin`, and several other things), and may even be processor specific. Many other compiled programming languages use C's pre-main code, and so have `main` but not all do. They are not linked against one of the crt*.o (or similar), but need their own startup code.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not.  You can write a library that will be used from another program.  But everything must have a beginning, and 'main' is the beginning of a C program...

(On Windows, the Win32 API specifies a WinMain, but it's the same thing, with a different name.)

Comment: That only holds true for hosted implementations; a freestanding implementation can use an entry point other than `main`.  See 5.1.2.1, paragraph 1.

Answer (score 0):

No, without the main method, the linker will not know where the start of the data segment in the program will start.